# how to do pagination in RESTFUL API in a effective way?

Tags: api, rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

I want to support pagination in my RESTful API.

My API method should return a JSON list of product via http://localhost/products/v1/getproductsbycategory, there are potentially thousands of products, and I want to page through them, so my request should look something like this:

```
public function getProductsByCategory($product_id,$page){
                $perPage=5;
                $start=($page-1)*$perPage;
                $stmt=$this->conn->prepare("SELECT id,product,description,destination_url,expiry_type,savings,expiry,title,last_updated_on  FROM products   WHERE product_id=?   ORDER BY  last_updted_on DESC LIMIT $start ,$perPage");
                $stmt->bind_param('i',$category_id);
                $stmt->execute();
                $productbycategory=$stmt->get_result();
                $stmt->close();
                return $productbycategory;
      }

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in a RESTful call, the URL should ideally be noun-based and not verbs. We are using HTTP verbs (GET, PUT, POST, etc) to do an action on a noun - product in your case.

So, the URL should be http://localhost/products/v1/category

This effectively means you are GETting product of type v1 based on category. To get a given page number, simply add it as a query parameter -

http://localhost/products/v1/category?page=1

and handle it accordingly in your GET implementation corresponding to `localhost/products/v1/category`

Hope this helps.

Comment: i fetch first five records on category_id  via post method.then i want to paginate them so how to implement in json format i did not find a logic

Comment: you can't 'fetch' via 'post'. You will need to GET it. Use jackson for java-json conversion.

Comment: REST does not care about URI design TBH. Humans however do. If the target of your API are humans, your missing the point of the idea behind REST in general - the independence of client implementations from server APIs which also simplifies automated semantic-based invocations through agents.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination has nothing to do with the JSON format per se - it's all about the query string in the URL and how the server interprets that.

Expanding on @Sampada's answer, you can have a URL like

`http://localhost/products/v1/category?pageSize=5&pageNumber=2`

and then you'll simply pick the corresponding elements on the server side (consider whether you'll want 0 or 1-based index for the pageNumber), and return them.

Additionally you can wrap this collection in an object that also provides links as to navigate to the previous/next/specific page - see [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) & [Richardson's Maturity Model level 3](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3).